# Ruby - Find the top 3 longest words in a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I want to be able to get the 3 longest words from a string. Is there a neat way of doing this without getting into arrays etc?

Comment: I think you will need an array anyway.

Comment: what if there are 3 words with the same length that fit the 3rd position do you care which of those 3 fit in? Is it by length then alphabetical?

Comment: I just want the 3 longest words, if they're equal I still count each one as one... if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>> str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
>> str.split.map { |s| s.gsub(/\W/, '') }.sort_by(&:length)[-3..-1]
=> ["adipisicing", "consectetur", "exercitation"]
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!
I changed it to .split.map { |s| s.gsub(/\b/, '') }.sort_by(&:length)[-3..-1] because I wanted to be able to have special characters like ÅÄÖ

Comment: `str.scan(/[[:alnum:]]+/).sort_by(&:length).last(3)`

Answer (score 1):

`"some string with words that are of different length".split(/ /).sort_by(&:length).reverse[0..2]`

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby 2.2 Enumerable `max_by`, `min_by`,`max`and `min` take an optional argument, allowing you to specify how many elements will be returned.

```
str.scan(/[[:alnum:]]+/).max_by(3, &:size) 
# => ["exercitation", "consectetur", "adipisicing"]
```